# ElasticSearch Segment merge not happening when deleted documents count is greater than 50%

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-7

**Elasticsearch version: 7.10.0**

I have an elasticsearch index with 8 shards in 8 different nodes and with a document count greater than 25 million documents(nested not included). It's an heavy update index. The document size grows over a period of time because of deleted documents. I did a search on this issue and read blogs like one below which tells a **segment will automatically be merged when the deleted docs count in that segment is greater than 50%.**

https://discuss.elastic.co/t/too-many-deleted-docs/84964/4

I did a **/_segment**s for the index and found segments like the below

```
"segments": {
                            "_bbx": {
                                "generation": 14685,
                                "num_docs": 27901732,
                                "deleted_docs": 23290932,
                                "size_in_bytes": 5071187083,
                                "memory_in_bytes": 137008,
                                "committed": true,
                                "search": true,
                                "version": "8.7.0",
                                "compound": false,
                                "attributes": {
                                    "Lucene87StoredFieldsFormat.mode": "BEST_SPEED"
                                }
                            },
```

Full response of /_segment call can be found here

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mLE2xw0u7lnogHnfzz65rWCBS8JrcnNm/view?usp=sharing

In many **segments like the one above the deleted_docs count is more than 75% of the num_docs** **but is still not getting merged**. We haven't set any max_merged_segment so the default is 5gb. We also haven't changed any MergePolicy and are using the default ones as of Es version 7.10.0.

Is my understanding correct ?

Any thoughts on this would be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The num_docs contains only the present documents and doesn't include the deleted documents.

So in this case we have 23,290,932 deleted documents out of a total of 51,192,664 (27,901,732 + 23,290,932) documents which means 45.5% are deleted in that segment. Hence segment merge didn't happen.

**Note** : Posted the same question in elasticsearch forums got this reply
https://discuss.elastic.co/t/elasticsearch-segment-merge-not-happening-when-deleted-documents-count-is-greater-than-50/277209

Comment: afaik, auto merge should happen when deleted documents count arrive 33%, by default(index.merge.policy.deletes_pct_allowed), did you change the default value or am I missing something?